# magento2 and gmail image proxy issue

Tags: magento2, google

i've faced with magento2 and gmail image proxy issue:
i'm sending transactional emails with images and gmail shows broken image because it has wrong URL inside (double dot in URL address):
[image]

it takes URL from Base URL and of course it correct and always was.
moreover, any other shipment and/or payment method works ok.

Kindly asking about any hints or suggestions.

p.s. same with some products:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are currently working in your localhost or under a private network this issue will happen because Gmail uses Google's secure proxy servers to serve images. If your website is publicly accessible you will not face this issue.

You can bypass the image url proxy but it is not recommended for security reasons.
Refer the below link

https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041?hl=en

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but my site is public of course.